# How to manually invoke create-drop from JPA on Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss-arquillian

I need this for an integration test. My environment is JBoss 7, EJB3 with JPA on Hibernate 4, H2 in-memory database and tests are run by Arquillian. I want to be able to drop the database and create it again will all tables based on `persistence.xml` and the entities. I know I can do it at the start of the application by specifying:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
```

But I need to do this manually from the code after the first drop and create happened.

Is it possible? What is the easiest way?

Comment: Do you really need to re-create the schema between tests or do you just need to truncate the data?

Comment: @FGreg - truncate all data and run the import.sql script would be enough. Workarounds exist, but I was more interested if there is a way to run in the way hibernate does it...

Comment: I'm not sure what the differences are between JUnit and Arquillian, but I have a solution for JUnit that truncates all data after each test. If you are interested I could share it, I just don't know how useful it will be since it relies pretty heavily on JUnit constructs.

Answer (score 3):

You can programatically do this in Hibernate.

```
config = new Configuration();
config.setProperty(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.SHOW_SQL, "true");
config.setProperty(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "create");
....
SchemaExport export = new SchemaExport( config );
export.create( true, true );
```

The JavaDocs are here:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/tool/hbm2ddl/SchemaExport.html

Comment: Does this work for you? I have tried it out but with no effect on the db

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to create the scripts manually. You can then use [ScriptRunner](http://pastebin.com/f10584951) (copy the class in your project):

```
public class YourIntegrationTestClass {
    private String url = "test-db-url";
    private String user = "user";
    private String pass = "pass";

    // run this before the test
    public void prepareDB() {
        // executes a script stored in test/resources/cucumber
        try {
            // use your driver here
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
            ScriptRunner runner = new ScriptRunner(conn, false, true);

            // use your db creation script here
            runner.runScript(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("createDB.sql")));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    // run this after the tests
    public void dropDB() {
            // use your driver here
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
            ScriptRunner runner = new ScriptRunner(conn, false, true);

            // use your db drop script here
            runner.runScript(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("dropDB.sql")));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your scriptRunner can use Hibernate ImportSqlCommandExtractor (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/tool/hbm2ddl/ImportSqlCommandExtractor.html) for a better SQL parse (see multiline and singleline extractor). Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Arquillian persistence extension to clear the database content after each test using the @UsingDataSet annotation on the test methods: https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-extension-persistence